# Markov's inequality with conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

How to apply Markov's inequality in case of conditional probability $P(X \ge a | Y \le a)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Can we write $P(X \ge a | Y \le a) \le \frac{E(X | Y \le a)}{a}$?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240246/conditional-markov-inequality

Answer (score 0):

I think so.

Let $a_1 \lt a$.

$E(X \ge a \mid Y = a_1) = \int_{0}^\infty xf_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y = a_1)dx \ge a\int_{a}^\infty f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y = a_1)dx = aP(X \ge a | Y = a_1)$

If we consider $E(X \ge a \mid Y \le a)$, I think this $P(X \ge a | Y \le a) \le \frac{E(X | Y \le a)}{a}$ will be true.